# Using rasterio to crop image using pixel coordinates instead of geographic coordinates

Tags: python, imagery, rasterio

I'm trying to extract a series of random patches of image from a larger satellite image (from worldview3). I want to extract patches of uniform size (say 512x512 for example). If it were a normal image, any number of libraries could do this easily. But I want to use rasterio to retain the geographic information of the image patch.

So far the code I've written identifies the upper left pixel coordinate using

```
image.bounds
```

and using the resulting bounding box to get the height and the width. Then I use numpy to randomly generate a new random coordinate within the image extent:

```
new_col = np.random.randint(min(bounds.left, bounds.right), max(bounds.left, bounds.right)-(size+1))
new_row = np.random.randint(min(bounds.top, bounds.bottom), max(bounds.top, bounds.bottom)-(size+1))
```

And then I subtract the patch size (512) from the new row and column and use those new coordinates as the minx, miny, maxx, maxy and crop from there using

```
mask(image, shapes=coords, crop=True)
```

With a non-georeferenced image where the upper left is (0,0) and the lower right is (M,N) this works flawlessly. Similarly for a NAIP image this seems to work. But with the worldview3 image the size is not uniform. I'll get an image size like 700x2000 for example, where I want it to be 512x512. My thought was that the NAIP image I tested with was in UTM, but that the worldview3 image was in lat/long so that subtracting the patch size from the random row and column didn't translate to a uniform pixel size. I still think the error has to do with lat/long but after reprojecting the image to UTM the problem persists.

So, is there any way I can crop the worldview3 image using rasterio but using pixel coordinates instead of geographic coordinates so that I can crop a uniform image size from the larger image but still retain the geographic information of the cropped image patch?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a window -[`rasterio.windows.Window`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.windows.html) to read by pixel offsets. The georeferencing can be easily calculated from the window using the source dataset [`window_transform`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html#window-transforms) method.

```
import random
import rasterio
from rasterio.windows import Window

with rasterio.open('input.tif') as src:

    # The size in pixels of your desired window
    xsize, ysize = 512, 512

    # Generate a random window origin (upper left) that ensures the window 
    # doesn't go outside the image. i.e. origin can only be between 
    # 0 and image width or height less the window width or height
    xmin, xmax = 0, src.width - xsize
    ymin, ymax = 0, src.height - ysize
    xoff, yoff = random.randint(xmin, xmax), random.randint(ymin, ymax)

    # Create a Window and calculate the transform from the source dataset    
    window = Window(xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize)
    transform = src.window_transform(window)

    # Create a new cropped raster to write to
    profile = src.profile
    profile.update({
        'height': xsize,
        'width': ysize,
        'transform': transform})

    with rasterio.open('output.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
        # Read the data from the window and write it to the output raster
        dst.write(src.read(window=window))
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks.

Comment: @user2856 that is great answer, I wonder if you couldplease elaborate how the generation of the random window works- not sure I understand the part of the src.width-xsize (and the same with the y) ? and why do we use random.randint?

Comment: @user2856 another thing i'm wondering is how do I do the connection between the coordinates to the pixel location ?

Comment: @Reut, the random.randint is because the OP wants random windows. The transform contains the geo coord info.